# Generate signed PKCS#7 without access to the PK

Tags: openssl, smartcard, sign, pkcs#7

I have a smart card which stores my private key and performs limited cryptographic operations, and I need to generate a PKCS#7 signed file. The library that came with the smart card doesn't support PKCS#7, but I can use it to generate signatures.

Is there any way I can use a mature, open source library, such as openssl, in order to build the PKCS#7 content, given the clear text payload, the certificate, and the *signature* (**not** the private key)?

I know I can call various functions in openssl to perform all operations at once (including signing), but that requires access to the private key, which my code can't extract.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs package provides an abstraction that allows calculation of the signature on the hardware device.

```
 public byte[] Sign(byte[] data, X509Certificate2 cert)
 {
     ContentInfo contentInfo = new ContentInfo(_sha256.ComputeHash(data));
     SignedCms signedCms = new SignedCms(contentInfo);
     CmsSigner cmsSigner = new CmsSigner(cert);
     cmsSigner.IncludeOption = X509IncludeOption.WholeChain;
     signedCms.ComputeSignature(cmsSigner);
     return signedCms.Encode();
 }
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.pkcs.pkcs9messagedigest?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0

Answer (score -1):

You can do it by creating an OpenSSL engine that will communicate with the card when private key operation is required.

Comment: Your answer is basically contained in the question; it's as if you had simply answered „yes”.

Comment: It's hard to answer anything more specific. OpenSSL has a pretty well documented ENGINE API [link](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/README.ENGINE) that you may use even with off the shelf OpenSSL installations by using dynamically loading engine as an external library. If you are linking your application with OpenSSL it may be even easier. All that pretty much depends what hardware architecture, platform, etc. you are going to use.
I have used OpenSSL exactly to generate CSR later establish TLS connections using a custom hardware equipped with a smart card, so the answer is yes

Comment: If you need clarification, please post a comment on the question.